# What is the effect of rewriting internal links with mod-rewrite on search engines

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo, search-engine

Currently I'm working on a project in which i have to add multi-language functionalities to an existing website. The used link structure (URL:) is similar to: "www.sitename.com/page-alias/", this must stay the same even after the multi-language update.

**URL's like this are not welcome**:

- www.sitename.com/en/page-alias/
- www.sitename.com/nl/different-alias/

I managed to get the job done with a .htaccess rewrites on both www. (there is an active rewrite to change without www. to with www.) and a rewrite that removes the /en/ & /nl/ part.

**The parts in my .htaccess file that does these changes**:

```
#from without www. to www.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#remove language from URL
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [R=NC,L]
RewriteRule ^nl/(.*)$ /$1 [R=NC,L]
```

But, the CMS we use (CMS made simple) creates a link structure similar to the URL's displayed in the list below. Unfortunately their doesn't seem to be an easy way of changing the link structure made by the CMS:

- sitename.com/nl/page-alias/
- sitename.com/en/different-alias/

*"No www." and "with language"*

**My question**:

Does the link structure created by the CMS have:

- a negative effect on the indexing in search engines?
- duplicated content?
- any other drawbacks / negative influences?

Or does the .htaccess solve this problem?

- Do search engines notice that those different URL's all belong to one page and still give it the right indexation?

Keep in mind that the whole website(source) gets filled with incorrect links.

I hope you guys can help me understand / solve this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the behaviour of search engine services / asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Comment: OK, that could be, but I think that there will be a htaccess related answer, at least that's what I'm hoping for. I'm almost certain that those redirects will influence my indexation within search-engines.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see what you are intending to do, you are trying to 302 redirect (do you mean [R,NC,L]?) :

www.sitename.com/en/page-alias  -> www.sitename.com/page-alias
www.sitename.com/nl/page-alias  -> www.sitename.com/page-alias

However, from the point of SEO, using the same URL to display the same content but in different languages is generally a bad idea.  Imagine, the content you will display to GoogleBot when the it comes to visit "www.sitename.com/page-alias"; you can only present one language to GoogleBot (say English), and the other language will not get indexed.

What is generally preferred from the SEO point of view, is that the 2 languages are given its own URL like

www.sitename.com/en/page-alias
www.sitename.com/nl/page-alias

Subsequently, you have to use the **hreflang** meta tag to indicate to google that these pages are the same content but in different languages - more on [Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en)

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.sitename.com/nl/page-alias" hreflang="nl" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.sitename.com/en/page-alias" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.sitename.com/en/page-alias" hreflang="x-default" />
```

I've taken a look at the CMS Made Simple, you should be able to use "Page URL" field to specify the pretty URL to accomplish this without having to rely on the "parent_alias/page_alias" framework.

It can be found  under "Edit Content" -> "Options" Tab -> "Page URL" field.  To use pretty URLs follow the [CMSMS Pretty URL](http://docs.cmsmadesimple.org/configuration/pretty-url) documentation.  It does involve the use of the pre-prepared .htaccess by CMSMS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use .htaccess.

The current version of CMS Made Simple has a "Page URL" field for content and the major modules. With this field you can define the exact URL for links (and Google canonical) so you can have it without the /en or /nl.

For Content the URL Field can be found under "Edit Content" -> "Options" Tab -> "Page URL" field.